# How to add values from a column of a multipage column to an array?

Tags: java, arrays, selenium

I have a table with multipage. I want to add all the values in a  particular column to a two-dimensional array. I first stored the values in the first page to an array(25 values in 1st page), clicked to the second page (4 values in 2nd page) and tried to store it in the array as a loop. The array is getting created, but lots of null values are also getting added. Here is my code:

Here pcount is number of pages, ccount = no. of rows in a page

```
for (int i=1; i< =pcount; i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j< ccount; j++)
    {
        Array [i][j]=T.getcolumn.get(j).getText();
    }
    if(i<pcount)
    T.getbutton().get(i).click(); //for clicking to the next page
}
```

If I print the values inside the loop, it prints correctly with the first page having 25 values and the 2nd page having 4 values

But if print it again  using the below code, I see so many null values added to the array values:

```
for (int i=1; i< =Array.length; i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<Array[i].length; j++)
    {
        System.out.println(Array[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Can anyone guide me why null values are getting added to my array

Comment: Its not an answer to your issue but still Why is your array starts with int i=1 instead of int i=0 ?

Comment: .... You named your array, Array ?? That's poor naming, you should use intuitive names so anyone reading your code can follow what the variables are for. (does not help with your issue but helps with your coding practices)

Comment: Since the name Array is not a keyword in java, its valid only @casualcoder

Comment: _But if print it again using the below code, I see so many null values added to the array values:_ The code below this sentence doesn't add anything to `Array`. It just prints the elements of `Array`. If `Array [i][j]=T.getcolumn.get(j).getText();` _prints correctly_ means `Array[i][i] != null`,  then look into the component type of the inner array (or more precisly into the type of the instances the inner array holds). Its `toString()` method is returning `null` or `"null"`.